# Mobile users unable to access Facebook app

Tags: facebook, mobile

My application works with descktop browser but it shows "The page you requested was not found." error by mobile browser. (the screenshot was made by chrome simulator but it shows same by real mobile(android) too)
[image]
I already set mobile site url to "Mobile Site URL" field from Setting tab
and turned on "Website - Mobile" checkbox on App Details tab.

I spent all my day trying to find solution without success. Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this problem can't be solved :(

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1051463851558493/

> Hey all,
>
> We recently identified a handful of apps misusing our mobile App
>   Center to redirect people to unauthorized sites. As a precaution, we
>   have temporarily turned off the ability for developers to direct to a
>   destination URL for any app in the "Mobile Site URL" field on the dev
>   site.
>
> We will be in touch shortly to discuss specific next steps with your
>   team.
>
> Best,
>
> The Facebook Team